# Adding table as a EventListener

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk, addeventlistener, lua-table

How can I add tables as a EventListener?
I'm working on a breakout game as a hello-world project and i would like to add the effect of "double ball". so basically i want to add balls to `balls table` then check if one of the balls hit the brick

my code works with

```
balls["ball"]:addEventListener( "collision", removeBricks )
```

but if i try the following:

```
balls:addEventListener( "collision", removeBricks )
```

i'm getting `Runtime error ...\main.lua:753: attempt to call method 'addEventListener' (a nil value)
stack traceback:`

what i've tried:

```
local balls = {}

balls["ball"] = crackSheet:grabSprite("ball_normal.png", true)
balls["ball"].name = "ball"

    function removeBricks(event)

            if event.other.isBrick == 1 then
                remove brick...
            end
    end

balls.collision = removeBricks
balls:addEventListener( "collision", removeBricks )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add event listener to a table. If you want to check bricks vs. ball collisions you should add event listeners to every ball or every brick

Answer (score 1):

you can try creating each instance of a ball instead of using a table and then try to add collision eventlistener on every ball try to look at the code

```
local Table = {}
local function generateBall(event)

   if "ended" == event.phase then
      local ball = crackSheet:grabSprite("ball_normal.png", true)
      ball.name = "ball"

      local function removeBricks(event)
          if "ended" == event.phase then
              if event.other.isBrick == 1 then
                remove brick...
            end
          end
      end

      ball:EventListener("collision", removeBricks)
      table.insert(Table, ball)
   end

end

Runtime:EventListener("touch",generateBall)
```

this way you can have different listener on every ball

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add balls in your table you can insert objects in table

```
local ballsTable = {}

function addBall()
    local ball = crackSheet:grabSprite("ball_normal.png", true)
    ball.name = "ball"

    ball.collision = function(self, event)
        if event.other.isBrick == 1 then
            event.other:removeSelf()
        end
    end
    ball:addEventListener( "collision" )

    table.insert(ballsTable, ball)
end
```